# Send "removeUser" request only on window close and not page refresh

Tags: reactjs, session, redux, socket.io, redux-persist

I am working on a Chat Application using `socket.io/ReactJS`. I am facing an issue wherein I need to remove a particular user(String value - Just a username) from the backend(`NodeJS/ExpressJS`) on Browser window close and not page refresh. As I am using `redux-persist`(Session Storage) I want to persist the user state when the window is refreshed, but when the user closes the browser window the user will be removed from the backend and obviously from session storage too.

In my App.js file I have below code to register for an event :

```
  removeUserBeforeUnload = () => {
    if (window.performance.navigation.type !== 1)
      // The socket request which removes the username from the backend
      socket.emit("removeUser", this.props.currentUser);
  };

  setupBeforeUnloadListener = () => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", ev => {
      ev.preventDefault();
      return this.removeUserBeforeUnload();
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // Registering event
    this.setupBeforeUnloadListener();
  }
```

I tried using window.performance.navigation.type but that doesn't seem to work.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you running your app in Chrome browser? Try without window like if (performance.navigation.type !== 1)

Comment: No Luck. The value still gets removed